# Iteratively generated modals with autogenerated ids - doesn't work! What's the problem?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I'm building a page that's supposed to display entries from a database in the form of textboxes, and each has a button that makes a call to the controller to delete that entry, based on its Id key. My boss then wanted me to add a modal to warn the user - your typical "Do you really want to...?"

To do so, I need to generate a modal codesnippet for each entry, and assign the relevant ids and data-targets automatically.

My current design looks like this:

```
@model System.Data.DataRow


<div class="input-group my-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-secondary tinybox" value="@Model[1]" name="ArtCategory">

    <div class="input-group-append">



        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary tinybox py-0" name="CatDelete" value="@Model[0]" data-toggle="modal" data-target="@("#" + Model[0] + "DeleteCategoryModal")">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </button>

    </div>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="@(Model[0] + "DeleteCategoryModal")">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Vill du verkligen radera denna kategori?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->

            <div class="modal-body">
                Kategorinummer: @Model[0]
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">


                @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteCategory", "Backoffice", FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model[0] }))
                {

                    <button type="submit" id="DeleteCategory" Name="CatDelete" value="@Model[0]" class="btn btn-dark">Bekräfta</button>
                    <script>
                        $('#DeleteArticle').click(function () {
                            $('#DeleteArticleModal').modal('hide');
                        });
                    </script>

                }
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Avbryt</button>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is submitted as a partialview and rendered a number of times. Model[0] is a numerical value. The idea is that the modals' id codes will be "3DeleteCategoryModal" for deleting category 3, etc.

The problem? The modals won't open. I click a button, nothing happens. For whatever reason, it can't find the modal segment with the right name. Curiously, when I wiew the compiled source code, it looks just fine:

```
            <div class="col-12 px-1">

<div class="input-group my-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-secondary tinybox" value="Stuff" name="ArtCategory">

    <div class="input-group-append">



        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary tinybox py-0" name="CatDelete" value="3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#3DeleteCategoryModal">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </button>

    </div>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="3DeleteCategoryModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Vill du verkligen radera denna kategori?</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->

            <div class="modal-body">
                Kategorinummer: 3
            </div>
```

So. How do I make this work?